# How to see ARP traffic (layer 2) on the host using docker container

Tags: docker

I am building a Kali Linux docker container using the following information:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM kalilinux/kali-rolling

LABEL version="1.0" \
      author="XYZ" \
      description="Custom Kali Linux Image"

RUN echo "deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free" > /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    echo "deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    echo "kali-docker" > /etc/hostname && \
    set -x && \
    apt-get -yqq update && \
    apt-get -yqq dist-upgrade && \
    apt-get clean && \
    apt-get install -yqq vim telnet nmap metasploit-framework sqlmap wpscan netcat

WORKDIR /root
```

and

```
# docker-compose.yml

version: "3.4"

services:
  kali:
    build:
      network: host
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./kali-root:/root
    tty: true
    privileged: true
```

What I'm trying to be able to do is run commands such as `tcpdump` to see layer 2 traffic that the host can see, but I'm not quite sure how to do this. I'm relatively new to docker and thought setting the `network` to `host` would sort of do that, but it actually seems like it just bridges the docker interface with the host rather than bridge it with the network, similar to how a VM's bridge mode works on a local LAN.

So if my VM's IP address on `eth0` is `192.168.1.25/24` which is bridged on my local network, how can I get my docker container *within* the VM to bridge as well, either sharing the eth0 adapter with the container or even bridging it so that it's 192.168.1.26 (assuming DHCP assigns it that)

How can I accomplish this? I'd ultimately like for the container to use the same interface/IP information as the host (e.g. can accept listening ports without any modifications, can see arp traffic), almost as if the container and the host are the exact same, but I'm not quite sure about how to accomplish this or if that's possible.

Comment: Docker is an isolation tool, and one of its key goals is to give each container a separated network environment.  You should run network diagnostic tools like this directly on the host.

Comment: Can this not be accomplished with macvlans? https://docs.docker.com/network/macvlan/